# Scala update tail of ListBuffer

Tags: scala

I would like to update the last value of a ListBuffer:

```
val res = ListBuffer[String]()
res += "a"
res += "b"
res.last = "c"
```

The compilation error is:

> Error:(28, 9) value last_= is not a member of
>   scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
>       res.last = "c"

I could use `res.update(1, "c")`, but it is linear in time, and I was looking for a constant time update, since accessing the last element is constant in time.

Is this achievable somehow ?

Comment: **ListBuffer** is designed to build lists incrementally, updates in constant time are not supported, try with an **ArrayBuildeR**.

Comment: then you try assign last element using res.last in scala is not working as you expect. You just tried call last method and assign to it new value, in scala you only can use special methods or operators for change most of data structures.

Comment: please consider changing type you are using as suggested in the comments above, ListBuffer is not the best option for this task..

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution using listBuffer is:

```
scala> val res = ListBuffer[String]()
res: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()

scala> res += "a"
res128: res.type = ListBuffer(a)

scala> res += "b"
res129: res.type = ListBuffer(a, b)

scala> res(res.size-1) = "c"

scala> res
res131: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(a, c)
```

Although it is recommended to use arrayBuilder for this case.

Let me know if it helps!!